# NiMH AAA battery outgassing after two charges? Is it dangerous?

Tags: batteries

I bought quality Ni-MH batteries of size AAA. I recharged them properly with the charger from the same manufacturer. Now after only two charges when I insert two of the 4 batteries into my flashlight there is outgassing occuring on two of the batteries. Can I still use them? What causes this behavior? I have used these type of batteries for up to 200 cycles and never had an issue before.

Comment: There's probably a short circuit in the device or the battery holder that shorted the batteries.

Comment: Define "outgassing." Could be measured by absolute pressure difference, concentration of gasses in sealed container, etc.  Or did you mean visible swelling?

Comment: Is the flashlight turned on and working while this occurs?

Comment: Outgassing means that there is literally gas coming out of the batteries while inserted into the battery holder..the flashlight is off..

Comment: The search term you are looking for is "venting". Replace them. Check with voltmeter if curious.

Comment: I think it is obvious that gas is not supposed to come out of consumer rechargeable batteries. Therefore, these are probably junk.